# ANTRL4 Praser. How to write the special case in grammar?

Tags: antlr4

I want to parse the following example:

```
class A {
    private int main(i<a) {
    }
}
```

and I want that the following error is yielded: `"line 2:21 mismatched input 'i' expecting ')'"`

BUT, it shows up `line 2:21 no viable alternative at input '(i'`.

This is my grammer:

```
//Identifiers
ID : [a-z] ( LETTER | DIGIT0 | '_' )*;
fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z];

type : PRIMITIVE_TYPE
     | CLASS_TYPE;

params : '(' ')' | '(' param_list ')';

param_list : /* epsilon */
           | type ID
           | param_list ',' type ID;
```

If I change the grammar like this:

```
params : '(' ')' | '(' param_list ')';
```

The expected error is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar is ambiquious (and incomplete, as the expression rules are not given here). `param_list` has an empty alt which is the same as the `'(' ')'` part. Also, there is no need for left recursion in `param_list`. Instead try this:

```
params: '(' param_list? ')';
param_list: type ID (',' type ID)*;
```